# This (do-While) loop doesn't want to stop despite meeting the condition - CS50-ps1

Tags: loops, cs50, do-while, ps1, long-long

What am I doing wrong? it doesn't want to stop.
I add printf to many spots to track all the results and they all meet the condition i set for the do-while loop

-CS50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cs50.h"



int main(void) 
{

 long long i = 0 ; // we must set it to (0), so it's not given a random big number.
 
 


do { 
 long long i = 0 ;
 long long n = get_long_long("Enter the card number:");
 printf("your card:%lli\n",n);

 while (n>0)
{
 n=n/10 ; 
 i=i+1 ; 
 printf("the number now is:%lli\n",n);
 printf("level is:%lli\n",i);
 }

printf("code ended-Digits are:%lli\n",i);


}
while (i>16 || i<13); 
printf("results reached");

}
```

Comment: It looks like it will get stuck. Your condition says while n > 0 and n will always be greater than 0 if you just keep dividing by 10. What values do you get when printing n in the while loop? What are you trying to accomplish?
Does the condition have to be n>0?

Comment: The loop aims to get the number of digits in a number by referring to i ,
the inside loop works because I am using long which only refers the real number.
if you keep dividing by 10 you reach somewhere around 0.555 for example.
which will be considered 0 by the long data type. 

my problem was with how I declared (i) again at the start of the (do-while)
where I had already declared it below main.
removed that and it worked. so it was all to the variable scope.
Thanks for your responce.